# Setting up the private file directory (nginx)

Tags: 7, files

**Problem**

I'm trying to set-up a private file directory for Drupal on an LEMP stack (Ubuntu 12.04, nginx, MySQL, PHP), I wasn't 100% sure about the permissions or set-up so I thought I'd ask, how should you do it?

**So Far**

It needs to be a folder which is writable by the webserver but not accessible from the web.

Example:

Location: drupal_root/privatefiles

Permission: `chgrp 775 www-data privatefiles`

Nginx config: (goes into `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite`):

```
server {
         listen 8080;
           root /srv/www/mysite/public;


           location ^~ /privatefiles {
             internal;
           }

        ...
        }
```

Would that be enough? It recommends on the official page to have the folder outside the Drupal root. What difference would this make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Perusio's config](https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx#private-file-handling), it has all the information and explanation you need. Here is a quote from it:

> This config assumes that private files are stored under a directory
>   named private. I suggest `sites/default/files/private` or
>   `sites/<sitename>/files/private` but can be anywhere inside the site
>   root as long as you keep the top level directory name private. (...)
>   Example: Calling the top level private files directory protected
>   instead of private.
>
> ```
> location ^~ /sites/default/files/protected {          
>   internal;        
> }
> ```
>
> Now any attempt to access the files under this directory directly will
>   return a 404.

...

> The usual practice involves setting up a directory outside of
>   files directory and giving write permissions to the web server user.
>   (...)  I think it to be less advisable, in the sense that now **there's another directory that is writable by the server.**
>
> I prefer to use a directory under files, which is the only one that is
>   writable by the web server, and use the above location (protected or
>   private) to block access by the client to it.

In short, marking it as internal is enough.

Comment: That's a brilliant resource. Thank you so much for pointing me to that.

Comment: @Attiks, with your permission I edited the answer to add the relevant snippet, since it is recommended to have _self contained_ answers. Cheers